# Showing and hiding image after clicking event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide `language_arrow_bottom` after clicking and show `language_arrow_up` and afterwards the other way around.

I cannot find the error in my code below? I know toggle in jquery but I don't want to use it for now.

Thanks in advance

I'm loading http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js

**HTML**

```
<a id="language_arrow_bottom" href="#nogo" title="Other languages‎"><img src="web/images/bottom_arrow.jpg" width="13px" height="13px" alt="" /></a>
<a id="language_arrow_up" href="#nogo" title="Close‎"  style="display:none;"><img src="web/images/bottom_arrow.jpg" width="13px" height="13px" alt="" /></a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#language_arrow_bottom').click(function(event)
    {
        $('#language_arrow_bottom').hide();
        $('#language_arrow_up').show();
    });

    $('#language_arrow_up').click(function(event)
    {
        $('#language_arrow_up').hide();
        $('#language_arrow_bottom').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: have you loaded jquery..?? Also make sure ID is unique..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to hide the `language_arrow_up` element by default, not the image inside it

```
<a id="language_arrow_up" href="#nogo" title="Close" style="display:none;"><img src="web/images/bottom_arrow.jpg" width="13px" height="13px" alt="" /></a>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x6M2G/)

Comment: @DipeshParmar sorry I didn't get... looks like the images are switching properly

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I actually hiiden a tag not the image inside. Post avove updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have hide the image on load...you should use display none in 'a' tag not in 'img'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but I think you probably need to add `return false;` calls at the end of your functions. Other code looks good

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gMgL9/)

Just make a  with the id and do the same procedure you tried with the  tag

```
<div id="language_arrow_bottom">
    <a href="#nogo" title="Other languages"><img src="web/images/bottom_arrow.jpg" width="13px" height="13px" alt="" /></a>
</div>

<div id="language_arrow_up" style="display:none;">
    <a  href="#nogo" title="Close"><img src="web/images/up_arrow.jpg" width="13px" height="13px" alt=""/></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Arun above.
Also, this code may be working, but you are using the same image, "web/images/bottom_arrow.jpg", so visually it may look like it's not working. Try using separate content within the  tag (or view the web inspector) to validate whether the code is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Another fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8A8LS/1/

```
<a id="language_arrow_bottom"><img src="http://www.iconshock.com/img_jpg/REALVISTA/3d_graphics/jpg/128/arrow_icon.jpg" width="13px" height="13px" alt="" /></a>

<a id="language_arrow_up"><img src="http://petacross.com/images/bwd_arrow.gif" width="13px" height="13px" alt="" style="display:none;" /></a>

$('a').click(function () {
  $('a img').show();
  $(this).find('img').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to set display "None" for "a" instead of the img as the image is inside the a tag and you are showing and hiding based on the "a" id.

```
<a id="language_arrow_bottom" href="#nogo" title="Other languages">
  <img src="web/images/bottom_arrow.jpg"  width="13px" height="13px" alt=""/>
<a id="language_arrow_up" href="#nogo" title="Close" `style="display:none;"`>
  <img src="web/images/bottom_arrow.jpg" width="13px" height="13px" alt="" />
```

The same js code will work here after the above changes.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#language_arrow_bottom').click(function(event)
    {
        $('#language_arrow_bottom').hide();
        $('#language_arrow_up').show();
    });

    $('#language_arrow_up').click(function(event)
    {
        $('#language_arrow_up').hide();
        $('#language_arrow_bottom').show();
    });
});
```